# Multi edit/save grid (hiddenfield + javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got a gridview which contains 10 rows where 1 of the columns is a combobox that can be edited. When I click on an "edit" button, all of the 10 rows becomes editable and I want to keep track of which rows I have changed so that I dont save all 10 rows to the DB if there has only been made changes to 2 of them. My toughts so far:

Make an extra hidden column in the grid (like a checkbox that tells that the row is edited)
On SelectedIndexChanged on the combobox im going to find a script that tells me the grid-row im currently editing and sets the checkmark in the hidden column for that row

Then when i press "Save" I can run through the lines of the grid and see which ones has the checkmark and then save those rows to the DB

Javascript is not my strong side so any help/tips would be appreciated, or a completely different solution would work too :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
Added a 
`<input type="hidden" id="hdnIsChanged" runat="server" />` 
in the ItemTemplate of the grid

Then in the grid on RowDataBound i found the hiddenField
`Dim hdnField As HtmlInputHidden = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("hdnIsChanged"), HtmlInputHidden)`

and dropdownlist
`Dim ddlTest As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddlTest"), DropDownList)`
`ddlTest.Attributes.Add("onChange", "Test('" + hdnField.ClientID + "');")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test(hiddenField) {
    var test = document.getElementById(hiddenField)
        test.value = "1"
}
</script>
```

Finally I could run through the rows of the grid and see which ones had changed:

```
For Each r As GridViewRow In gvTest.Rows
    Dim hdnField As HtmlInputHidden = DirectCast(r.FindControl("hdnIsChanged"), HtmlInputHidden)

    If hdnField.Value = "1" Then
        // do updates
        End If
Next
```